# How to perform CURD on mysql using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, backbone.js

I am new in Node.js. Well i have experience in Backbone on Client side and Server side using PHP Laravel framework.

I want know is following connection/communication workflow is correct or possible:

[image]

1. My application is being designed using Backbone and its stacks and i can use Backbone model/collection to make service calls. But on Server side is it possible to create web service using Node.js (Without using any Server side scripting like PHP).
2. Am i using Node.js in correct direction at server end.
3. Here Node.js will perform CURD operations on database and return the result in JSON format.

Please suggest me what we can do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Node.js is fantastic at building scalable CRUD JSON APIs to your backend database.

You can use MySQL, MongoDB, Redis or any other number of databases on the backend.  You'll find support in [NPMjs.org](http://npmjs.org) for all the popular databases.

In addition to enhanced performance of Node.js over PHP, you can also make multiple database calls in parallel with Node.js.  That's something PHP can't do.  In PHP you must make your database calls sequentially.  In Node.js you can make several calls in parallel so long as the calls are not interdependent.

Comment: Thanks. I got it...and i give good go for it node-mysql npm for now.